# Alter Image color in tableView in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView with menu options. In this menu options I have images and labels.

I would like when I click in one option the icon image change current color to another color.

```
var menuNameArr : Array = [String]()
var iconImageNormal : Array = [UIImage]()
var iconImageSelected : Array = [UIImage]()

@IBOutlet weak var imgLogo: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    menuNameArr = ["Menu", "Map", "Favorites", "Orders", "Settings", "Help"]
    iconImageNormal = [UIImage(named: "icon-coffee-cup-gray")!, UIImage(named: "icon-placeholder-gray")!,
                       UIImage(named: "icon-star-gray")!, UIImage(named: "icon-shopping-cart-gray")!,
                       UIImage(named: "icon-settings-gray")!, UIImage(named: "icon-help-gray")!]
    iconImageSelected = [UIImage(named: "icon-coffee-cup-green")!, UIImage(named: "icon-placeholder-green")!,
                         UIImage(named: "icon-star-green")!, UIImage(named: "icon-shopping-cart-green")!,
                         UIImage(named: "icon-settings-green")!, UIImage(named: "icon-help-green")!]

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return menuNameArr.count

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MenuTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MenuTableViewCell

    cell.imgIcon.image = iconImageNormal[indexPath.row]

    cell.lblMenuName.text! = menuNameArr[indexPath.row]
    cell.lblMenuName.textColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 183.0/255.0, green: 183.0/255.0, blue: 183.0/255.0, alpha: 1)

    return cell
}
```

Does anyone know how I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure you set your UITableViewDelegate, then add the following function to your class:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){

    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? MenuTableViewCell {
        cell.imgIcon.image = iconImageSelected[indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the delegate of tableview didSelectRowAtIndexPath .

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? MenuTableViewCell {
        cell.imgIcon.image = iconImageSelected[indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: Thank you! I used the @toddg solution because I'm using swift 3